# XL timing belt missing Dimension!

Tags: gears, 3d-printing, pulleys, power-transmission, timing

I'm trying to design and 3d print a XL pulley. I think there is a missing dimension that I can't find in the spec tables.

we've got pitch circle, teeth height, belt thickness... but I can't find location of pitch circle relative to other two!

Is it in the middle of base belt thickness? **I need the red question mark dimension.**

[image]

Comment: (2.3 - 1.27) / 2 but the pulley diameter will be anything as long as it has a complete number of teeth... Large or small.

Comment: So, it is in the middle of base belt thickness.

Comment: Well, that is what you called it... But I don't think what you labelled is what you need.

Comment: so what dimension I need? pitch circle distance to somewhere... any where.

Comment: Dimensions of the driver pulley and the gear ratio, then you can calculate the size of the driven pulley which you want to make.

Comment: all that applies to pitch circle. but to design a pulley precisely we need to know where pitch circle exactly located relative to other dimensions, right?

Comment: How about the center of rotation?

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://us.misumi-ec.com/pdf/fa/2009/inch_p295.pdf

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful. So it leads to this, the Red dimension is 0.78mm, not 0.515mm.

Comment: the important dimensions are relative to the pulley, not to the outside of the belt.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is called the belt's neutral axis. The neutral axis is what coincides with the pulley's pitch circle. You have to look this up for each belt, because it depends on the way the belt is made.

But if this is a synchronous belt and pulley system, you are doing things backwards. The pulley profile is the established standard, and the belt guys have to make their different belt types all work with the same pulley. But buy belts and pulley from same manufacturer if you want any real hope of success with high speeds and loads.

https://us.misumi-ec.com/vona2/detail/110300405510/

Comment: I am going to 3d print the pulley. So I can use any belt I can find since I can change the pulley dimensions.